# Contao Wrap Leff and Right Class TL_DCA Fields

Tags: css, contao

I am using TL_DCA Feature in Contao and i want to wrap the fields inside left and right container.

```
$GLOBALS['TL_DCA']['table_name'] = array
(
    // Config
    'config' => array
    (
        'dataContainer' => 'Table',
    ),

    // List
    'list' => array
    (),

    // Fields
    'fields' => array
    (
        'field1' => array
        (
            'label' => array('Suchname', 'Suchname'),
            'exclude' => true,
            'inputType' => 'text'
        ),
        'field2' => array
        (
            'label' => array('Firma', 'Firma'),
            'exclude' => true,
            'inputType' => 'text'
        ),
        'field3' => array
        (
            'label' => array('Name', 'Name'),
            'exclude' => true,
            'inputType' => 'text',
            'eval' => array('mandatory' => true)
        ),
        'field4' => array
        (
            'label' => array('Vorname', 'Vorname'),
            'exclude' => true,
            'inputType' => 'text'
        ),
    )
)
```

Wrap Field and Filed 2 inside left class and Field 3 and Field 4 inside right class. So please help here.

Thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: You need to provide more information, I did not get what you mean.

Comment: i need html structure like <div class="left><-- Field 1, Field 2 --></div> <div class="right><-- Field 3, Field 4 --></div>

Comment: But that has nothing to do with the DCA. This is done in templates.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to specific css classes for the fields:

```
'eval' => array('tl_class'=>'w50'),
```

w50 stands for width = 50%

for example:

```
   'field1' => array
    (
        'label' => array('Suchname', 'Suchname'),
        'exclude' => true,
        'inputType' => 'text',
        'eval' => array('tl_class'=>'w50'),
    ),
    'field2' => array
    (
        'label' => array('Firma', 'Firma'),
        'exclude' => true,
        'inputType' => 'text'
        'eval' => array('tl_class'=>'w50'),
    ),
```